# How to view call stack from Borland c++ 5.02 application's crash dump

Tags: c++, visual-c++, borland-c++

I've just got a crash dump of an application that was implemented and built by Borland C++ 5.02. This crash dump was generated by WER referenced [this site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process/). I used winDBG to analyze but could not get correct call stack. It shown below warning:
[image]

As I investigated, the warning message means WinDBG cannot find symbol information for the process. I also found that the symbol file should be kind of *.pdb, but Borland c++ 5.02 does not have any setting items to create this *.pdb file.
So, is there any way that I can view the correct stack call of this crash dump? If not, do I have to convert this project to VC++ so that future crash dump can be more easily analyzed?

Comment: I strongly suggest you update _"Borland C++ 5.02 - (__1997__) Final independent release of the Borland C++ IDE"_ source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B  ie it's 20 year old.  MSVC 2017 community edition is free for personal and small company use and is full featured.

Comment: And mingw is open source